# How to read the error message from Request.CreateErrorResponse?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

My WebAPI method returns an error response:

```
return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Something bad happened");
```

On my client end (an MVC project), I want to display the error message, but unable to get the message "Something bad happened" to display:

```
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    ViewBag.Error= response.ReasonPhrase; 
}
```

Other than ReasonPhrase, I've tried `response.ToString()`, `response.Content.ToString()`, and `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`. None of them get me the message. How come Postman is able to display the message?

Any ideas how I can access the message string?

Comment: `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` should do it. Can you post the code that you tried doing that? There may be some other error.

Comment: I think I know the problem, added as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

If your response content comes back as `application/json`, you can deserialize it with `Json.Net` like this:

```
if(!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var errors = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    var message = errors[HttpErrorKeys.MessageKey];

    // message is "Something bad happened"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` returns a `Task<string>`, not a `string`. You'd need to use

```
response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
```

or if your method is marked `async` you can await it.

```
string message = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Hmm this may be it...will try it out. Thanks.

Comment: That get it for you?

Answer (score 0):

That's what I do to get error message. when you complete your debug, you can change return type

```
       public string someRequest()
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            return "Ok";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
         return e.Message;
        }
    }
```